Exception Handling in Windows
Windows provides the following exception handling frameworks:

Structured Exception Handling (SEH)
Vectored Exception Handling (VEH)

SEH is just the Windows's version of the C++ try-catch, and Microsoft themselves have suggested to use the C++ try-catch blocks. I don't want to use try-catch everywhere but have a single 'catch-all' exception handler.
That leads to VEH, which, unlike SEH is not a frame-based exception handling construct i.e., it's for the entire process and not just each thread.
But there is one more technique - UnHandledExceptionFilter. This is actually part of SEH. In Windows, the __except part contains a filter expression (described in detail here), which decides whether to invoke the exception handler (which follows the __except clause or pass it to other exception handlers in the stack).
__try {
    // guarded code
}
__except ( /* filter expression */ ) {
    // the exception handler (as Windows calls it)
}

Now, if none of the exception handlers are matched, then the exception handler set using the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter method is invoked. To me, it looks like a non-frame exception handler (like VEH), but it's actually frame-based, since it's the last exception handler which catches all exceptions that weren't caught by the SEH's __except clause. In my case, if I don't write any try-except blocks, the method I set using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter gets invoked - which makes sense because there were 0 exception handlers, so by default, all exceptions are considered 'unfiltered' and trigger the UnhandledExceptionFilter.
Now, I'm not sure which one to use - VEH or UnhandledExceptionFilter. VEH is not frame-based and gets invoked before UnhandledExceptionFilter. Both can handle all 'uncaught exceptions'.
Next, after catching an exception (using VEH or UnhandledExceptionFilter) on a worker thread (threads created by app), what is the expectation? Can the app continue?
Here's a sample scenario: If there was a division by zero or access violation due to a bug on a worker thread, I'd like to signal the main thread and kill the worker thread. The main thread finalizes all my structures, shows a message box to user with two options - Restart & Quit, and if user chooses to Restart, initialize all my structures again. This is possible but is this recommended?
Regarding return values, VEH documentation says:

To return control to the point at which the exception occurred, return
EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION (0xffffffff). To continue the handler
search, return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH (0x0).

and UnhandledExceptionFilter documentation says there are the following return values - EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH and EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER, different from VEH.
What if an exception occurs in the main thread? Then, the VEH and UnhandledExceptionFilter gets invoked on main thread. I can't kill the thread in that scenario. What is Window's recommendation?
There's also this other stackoverflow post which says VEH doesn't replace UnhandledExceptionFilter and should be used as a diagnostic tool only, but I didn't understand.
Basically, I want to know what is Windows's recommended way to cleanly handle exceptions in a Windows app. Summarizing my questions as follows:

VEH vs UnhandledExceptionFilter - which one to use and why? What is Windows's recomendation?
After catching an exception (in both cases - main thread or worker thread), how should the app behave?

Note: I'm aware that killing a thread is not a good practice and has some consequences (one being, the stack doesn't unwind), but that's not the main focus of this post. If I kill the thread, I don't have to deal with recursive exceptions and I can potentially restart the app in the same process space.
Update1: I cannot use try-catch for few reasons - it works only if you throw an exception (I might be wrong here)... It doesn't catch division by zero (as shown here). I've never used try-catch, so I'm not hands-on with it, but it's a guideline in my project to never use try-catch, unless a third-party API which throws, is used. All funcs are marked noexcept. There are other reasons, but that'd digress from this post.

"Basically, I want to know what is Windows's recommended way to cleanly handle exceptions in a Windows app." vs  "Microsoft themselves have suggested to use the C++ try-catch blocks." Why are you ignoring Microsoft's advice?

The "recommended" way is to only catch an exception that you can safely handle and recover from. Otherwise, don't catch it at all, let the system handle it.  It might be a system error (page guard, etc), or it might produce an error dump allowing devs to fix the root cause. Don't just catch exceptions blindly, you might do more harm than good (not all exceptions are fatal).

@Botje, they have recommended C++ try-catch instead of their own try-except. This is fine, but about the catch-all exception handlers - VEH vs UnhandledExceptionFilter?

@RemyLebeau, Both in VEH and UnhandledExceptionFilter, I'm only intending to catch the relevant exceptions (like EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO). The rest of the exceptions which I have no knowledge of handling, will go to a default case in a switch statement which returns EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH, so that other exception handlers can get invoked... at least, that's how I'm visualizing. But I'm not sure which one to use - VEH or UnhandledExceptionFilter and how to exit/return from them when invoked by different threads (main threads/worker threads).

@NightFuryLxD I would not recommend handling EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO at a global level to begin with. It should be handled (if at all) at the location where it occurs. What is your actual goal by catching exceptions globally?


SEH is just the Windows's version of the C++ try-catch

SEH is what Windows uses to implement C++ try-catch. On a superficial level, it is similar, but normally you're better off not interacting with SEH directly.

That leads to VEH, which, unlike SEH is not a frame-based exception
handling construct i.e., it's for the entire process and not just each
thread.

Forget about Vectored Exception Handlers. They will not help you. <= I think based on the other statements in your question.

Next, after catching an exception (...) on a worker thread (threads created by app),
what is the expectation? Can the app continue? Here's a sample
scenario: If there was a division by zero or access violation due to a
bug on a worker thread, I'd like to signal the main thread and kill
the worker thread.

With your scenario: no. If a C++ Worker Thread causes an SEH Access Violation, your complete process is corrupted and you are better off terminating it.
The UnhandledExceptionFilter comes into play here insofar as you could use it to try to do some last second clean up -- but I've come to learn over the last decade that the best way in current Windows versions is to just register you application to record a WER dump and then the system will handle writing a core dump for you.

Basically, I want to know what is Windows's recommended way to cleanly
handle exceptions in a Windows app.

For C++ exceptions you:
Do not use /EHa
and possibly wrap all you thread roots in:
} catch(specificex_types&) { ... }
} catch(std::execption&) { ... maybe you can still do something }
} catch(...) { ... pretty fatal, try to report and re-init }


VEH vs UnhandledExceptionFilter - which one to use and why? What is Windows's recomendation?

You use neither. (This is just the short of it. There are some good use cases for UnhandledExceptionFilter, but these don't help with what you asked in this question.)

After catching an exception (in both cases - main thread or worker
thread), how should the app behave?

After encountering any non-C++ SEH exception, you app should write a core dump (or rather, have the system write one) and exit.

Thanks for the answer. I've updated the post explaining why I can't use try-catch. So, here's how I am thinking of proceeding - Use the VEH or the UEH to prepare a diagnostic report, launch a new process and let current process, which had raised an exception, terminate. I have seen Visual Studio and Outlook restart suddenly as I use them, so I think starting a new process is valid (I don't have any documentation.. this is just based on experience). Thoughts?

@NightFuryLxD - might I note that integer division by zero is undefined behavior in C++, so from a language POV you should be avoiding that. Also: Doing anything complex in the UHE is operating in the context of a "corrupted" process. Maybe have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/recovery/registering-for-application-restart and friends.

SEH is the Microsoft low level exception handling system. It is internally used in C++ programs to implement the standard try-catch C++ exception handling, and used to be provided to C programmers who could wish to implement some exception handling in C.
But even Microsoft documents recommends that C++ programs use the standard try-catch exception handling.
